# Function calls, assignment, and 'underlying types' in Go

Tags: go, types

I'm learning Go (like it so far) but I've run into an interesting problem. The code that fails to compile is:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type MyInt int

func (i MyInt) Double() MyInt {
    return i + i
}

func AddTwo(i int) int {
    return i + 2
}

func main() {
    var a int = 3
    var x MyInt = a  // Why does this fail?
    fmt.Println(x.Double())
    var y int = AddTwo(x)  // Why does this fail?
    fmt.Println(y)
}
```

Here's the Go Playground link: [MyInt](https://play.golang.org/p/MEqV9yJPBh)

When I try to run this, I get the following errors:

```
  prog.go:17: cannot use a (type int) as type MyInt in assignment
  prog.go:19: cannot use x (type MyInt) as type int in argument to AddTwo
```

However, if I'm reading the spec correctly, this code should compile. First of all, the underlying type of `MyInt` is `int` [according to this section](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types). In fact, one of the examples given is `type T1 string` and it says the underlying type of `T1` is `string`. So why can't I assign `a` to `x`? Don't they have the same underlying type? Same goes for the function call to `AddTwo()`. Isn't `x` has the underlying type `int`? Why can't I use it as an `int` argument?

Also, how come `Double()` compiles at all? In the expression `i + i` I'm adding two `MyInt` values. The fact that it compiles suggests that `MyInt` *is* an `int` at least in some sense.

Anyhow, I'm a bit confused. So I thought the point of declarations like `type MyInt int` was that now you can add methods to primitive types. But if you lose the ability to treat them as `int` (needing to cast), then what's the point of having this whole 'underlying type' business?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go has a strict type system. Just because your type is merely an alias for `int` doesn't mean you can interchange the two freely, you'll still have to do a type conversion. Below is a working version of your main, here's the code on play ground; https://play.golang.org/p/kdVY145lrJ

```
func main() {
    var a int = 3
    var x MyInt = MyInt(a)  // Why does this fail?
    fmt.Println(x.Double())
    var y int = AddTwo(int(x))  // Why does this fail?
    fmt.Println(y)
}
```

Comment: Then why does Double() compile in the first place? How can I add (using operator '+') two MyInt values? Oh, and by the way, does this mean boxing/unboxing of MyInt values to/from int values?

Comment: @LajosNagy method resolution and assignment follow different rules, assignment is more strict. If you have two `MyInt` values you can add them the same as you would two `int` values, however you can't add an `int` and a `MyInt` without a type conversion because it will say "mismatched types". example here; https://play.golang.org/p/KNqdbqGpfd I'd have to read the spec to give a reasonable explanation of how method resolution is done in Go so I think you'd be better served looking into it yourself. I simply avoid situations that require anything more than common sense to know what will happen.

Comment: Sorry, one more thing: do you know if Go uses boxing/unboxing for MyInt? I mean, is it the size of an int or not? (It can matter if there's a cost to using MyInt instead of int.)

Comment: @LajosNagy nbd, good quesionts. They are the same size, here's another example demonstrating that ;) https://play.golang.org/p/xSm_OX47HO

Comment: @LajosNagy This isn't boxing, there is no actual conversion executing at runtime.  It's merely a compile time safety check to make sure you don't add Dollars and Degrees (ie: don't add unlike types together, regardless of underlying type, unless you say so by "converting" the type.

Comment: to add to that, if the underlying data types are different, ie: int and float64, then there is a runtime conversion to perform